# How to set several classes for React-Router 6 NavLink?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How can I assign several classes to className while using `NavLink isActive`? Actually I want to add a base link styles like font-size and if it is active then active class should be applied otherwise base styles class.

My component:

```
        <NavLink
          to={category.url}
          state={category}
          onClick={closeMenu}
          className={() => (category.id === locationId ? classes.active : classes.link)}
        >
          {category.name}
        </NavLink>
```

I know that I can use template literals and set active class like this:

```
className={() => (category.id === locationId ? `${classes.active} ${classes.link}` : classes.link)}
```

But is there a more cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several of the `NavLink` component's props take a callback function that is passed an `isActive` property.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

What you can do is pass a callback function to the `NavLink` that returns the combined `className` string value.

Example:

```
<NavLink
  to={category.url}
  state={category}
  onClick={closeMenu}
  className={({ isActive }) => 
    [
      classes.link,
      isActive ? classes.active : null,
    ]
      .filter(Boolean)
      .join(" ")
  }
>
  {category.name}
</NavLink>
```

If you don't need know which link is actually active and you really do just want to set the classes on `category.id === locationId` then apply the same logic under this different condition.

```
<NavLink
  to={category.url}
  state={category}
  onClick={closeMenu}
  className={() => 
    [
      classes.link,
      category.id === locationId ? classes.active : null,
    ]
      .filter(Boolean)
      .join(" ")
  }
>
  {category.name}
</NavLink>
```